# why creating the opportunity record fails when a donor submit a donation on click & pledge platform?

Tags: integration, opportunity, website-integration, npsp

[image]there is a click and pledge platform integrated with Salesforce . whenever I submit a donation by a web form connected to Salesforce a contact record , a household(account) record and a record in C&P data created automatically.
but as classics , when you create a contact and account , an opportunity record will be created associated to that contact and record
this is the problem I have . this record is not produced because the id which is created by click and pledge on sales force is too long for SF and the insert clause fails
I don't know how to fix and how to check the back end configuration

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting pledge support . Looks like they might need to change the field size in salesforce.